# How to convert javax.mail.BodyPart with content type "Application/zip" to list of java.io.File objects?

Tags: java, file, email, zip

I have BodyPart object from email which is a .zip archive. And i need to extract all files from it, but can't find any solution. 
I tried this:

```
List<File> files = new ArrayList<>();
        try (ZipInputStream zis = (ZipInputStream)bodyPart.getInputStream()) {
            ZipEntry zipEntry;
            while ((zipEntry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                LOG.info("Unzipping: {}", zipEntry.getName());
                File file = new File(zipEntry.getName());
                files.add(file);
            }
        }
        return files;
```

But it throws exception on casting `bodyPart.getInputStream` to `ZipInputStream'`.

Is there another way to convert `.zip` `BodyPart` to list of archive's content?

Comment: Using `new File(zipEntry.getName())` is not doing what you think it is. Try saving the entire ZIP file to a local file, then open up a new [`ZipFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html) or use NIO's ZIP file system provider.

Comment: Instead of casting do a ``ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(bodyPart.getInputStream())``.